# Android: Blue line under the Tab not displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity. Inside that activity i have implemented TabHost.OnTabChangeListener. Through TabFactory and TabInfo class I have added 2 tabs TAB1 and TAB2. Initially everything works fine. But when I click a button that is there in TAB2 and trying to call TAB1 function, the TAB1 Fragment is visiable but the BLUE line under TAB1 is not coming. Any idea how to make it selectable. The code I am using to call TAB1 fragment function in TAB2 is as follows:

```
((MyActivity)mContext).onTabChanged("TAB1");
((MyActivity)mContext).mTabHost.getTabWidget().requestLayout();

android.app.FragmentManager fm = ((MyActivity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
Tab1_Fragment fragment = (Tab1_Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("TAB1");      
fragment.updateTab1Data(bundleData);
```

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: please share screen shot .

Comment: How to add screenshot here?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the below code:

`((MyActivity)mContext).onTabChanged("TAB1");
 ((MyActivity)mContext).mTabHost.getTabWidget().requestLayout();`

And use code like:

`((MyActivity)mContext).mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);`